# How to populate MQTT topic list dynamically on node js

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am using mqtt-node to get subscribed messages. But the problem is the topic list for subscribing will be appended through an API. But the appended topic list is not being read by the mqtt connection while subscribing for other topics. Please advice or suggest a suitable way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no topic list.

The only way to discover what topics are in use is to either maintain a list external to the broker or to subscribe to a a wildcard and see what messages are published.

It's important to remember that topics only really exist at the moment a message is published to one. Subscribers supply a list of patterns (they can include wildcards like `+` or `#`) to match against those published topics and any matching messages are delivered.

Comment: I believe subscribing to a wild card is a hack which could be vulnerable in some cases, so I have avoided it for security reasons

Comment: In what way? A properly deployed system should include a ACL so even if you subscribe to `#` you will only ever see the messages on topics you are allowed to see.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Most of deployed well-known systems ever built(fb, AWS, G-Colud) are already depending on ACL even though those are hackable these days. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Wildcard subscriptions are NOT a security problem, especially since you have no control over what topics a client may try to subscribe to.

Comment: Ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

You maintain an array of Topics

```
var topics = [
  "test/1",
  "test/2",
  "test/3"
]
```

When a new Topic arrives via the API, you will need to first unsubscribe from the existing Topics

```
client.unsubscribe(topics)
```

then add the new Topic

```
topics.push(newTopic)
```

then re-subscribe

```
client.subscribe(topics)
```

This is what worked best for me when I have this use case.

Keep in mind that the time between unsubscribing and re-subscribing, messages could be Published and your client would not see them due to not being subscribed at the time. This is easy to overcome if you can use the RETAIN field on your Publishers....but in some use cases, this isn't practical.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my purpose is not to unsubscribe from any topic. So if I get any topic name through api then I may call `client.subscribe(topics)`. As far I'm concerned mqtt takes care of the topics that are not publishing at all. Now I need to know if any of the subscribed topics are not publishing then do I need to unsubscribe them.